# A non-numeric value encountered in Laravel script

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my Laravel script on a page this error appears:

> "A non-numeric value encountered (View: /home/grammer/public_html/test/core/resources/views/admin/apiServices.blade.php)"

for this line

> ```
> <td>{{ $key+1 }}</td>
> ```

my page codes:

```
@extends('admin.layouts.master')
@section('page_icon', 'fa fa-suitcase')
@section('page_name', 'API Services')
@section('body')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="tile">
                <h3 class="tile-title">API Services List</h3>
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Serial</th>
                        <th>Service ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Category</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Min</th>
                        <th>Max</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @foreach($items as $key => $item)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $key+1 }}</td>
                            <td>{{ isset($item->service->id) ? $item->service->id : $item->service}}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item->name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item->category }}</td>
                            <td>{{ isset($item->rate) ? $item->rate : $item->price_per_k }} $</td>
                            <td>{{ $item->min }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item->max }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: what's the line you defined `$items`  ?

Comment: in this page, we can see a site services with its api, items are services in the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this :

```
<td>{{ (int) $key + 1 }}</td>
```

**or** Add this:

```
$key = (int) $key; // GET NUMBER FROM VARIABLE
```

Comment: tnx, it worked, but now appear : `Trying to get property 'service' of non-object (View: /mylocal/core/resources/views/admin/apiServices.blade.php)"` for this line : `<td>{{ isset($item->service->id) ? $item->service->id : $item->service}}</td>`

Comment: Try to use `$item['service']` ? or `$item['service']->id` ? Something like that :)

Comment: Ah! Just create a new question and add all results you get them from dd($item) ;)